# Can't play video from url - Livecode

Tags: livecode

I can't play video from url. And this my code:

```
on preOpenCard
   put URL "http://elanorb.on-rev.com/lessons/MalteBrill.mp4" into player "Player"
end preOpenCard
```

And this my error:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax for that is

set the filename of player "Player" to "http://elanorb.on-rev.com/lessons/MalteBrill.mp4"

Marks example contains  the keyword URL before the url. But this will not work. At least here in LC 6.6x.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to put a URL into a player, you're doing the same as when you try to put text into a field. A player can't contain text, hence the error.

You can set the filename property of a player to a URL:

```
put "http://elanorb.on-rev.com/lessons/MalteBrill.mp4" into myURL
set the filename of player "Player" to myURL
```

This doesn't always work, depending on load time and encoding. Let me know if you're still having a problem playing the movie.

Comment: I try it, but the error

Object: can't set script while it is executing

Comment: Right, I had a typo in the script. It should work now.